# How can I use for loop in array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, for-loop

I'm trying to use for loop in array but it is not work

```
$get_row_in_book = $this->get_data('books')->books_much;
$data = array(
    for ($i=0;$i<$get_row_in_book;$i++){
        'moon'=>$i
    }
    );
$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

Comment: _"not work"_ means what exactly? the "greater than" here `$i>$get_row_in_book` looks wrong. I guess you want smaller than? (the second "argument" in a for is "do while this is true; which will never be in your case)

Comment: there's a syntax error: you cant have a for loop inside an array declaration. And adding multiple times different values ($i) to the same key ('moon') doesn't make sense. Do you want an array of moons instead maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You defenitely have some syntax issues here, because you cant have a for loop inside an array declaration and inside that `'moon'=>$i` doesn't do anything.
There's several possibilities of what you might want to achieve:

1st, unlikely:

```
$data=array();
for ($i=0;$i<$get_row_in_book;$i++){
    $data['moon'] = $i;
}
// overwrites 'moon' with the last value (assuming $get_row_in_book=6)

// OUTPUT
$data = ['moon' => 5];
```

2nd a plausible guess:

```
$data=array();
for ($i=0;$i<$get_row_in_book;$i++){
    $data['moon'][] = $i;
}
// adds an array 'moon' with all $i to $data (assuming $get_row_in_book=6)

// OUTPUT
$data = ['moon' => [0,1,2,3,4,5]];
```